# The "visible area" of a control?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, uiscrollview, canvas, scrollview

I have a Canvas within a ScrollViewer. The Canvas have a size of 600x600 and the ScrollViewer
400x400. If i scroll to the right side, i can't see 200pxl left side of the Canvas. Therefore my area of Canvas begins at x=200 but actually the visible area at x=0. Is there any way to get so "visile area" of a control by a property or something like that ?

Regards
Gepro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What are you looking for?

Choose the one from the list below:

- [ContentVerticalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.contentverticaloffset.aspx)
- [ContentHorizontalOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.contenthorizontaloffset.aspx)
- [ViewportWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.viewportwidth.aspx)
- [ViewportHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.viewportheight.aspx)